# Consuming Spring cloud config using Spring REST service (non-boot rest service)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm just curious, is it possible to consume Spring Cloud config by a Spring REST service which is not a Spring boot application. If it is possible, where to define the properties in a Spring REST service. I meant, where should I define

`spring.cloud.config.uri` etc.

Or, only Spring boot applications are allowed to consume Cloud configuration?

Any thought would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well spring boot just bootstrap all configuration automatically . so for simple spring application you have to config it manually and define the cloud config server beans in your application configuration file . it could be pure old fashion xml files or just using java code configuration with @Configuration. you could find some samples in github

Comment: Thanks! I just found some Spring document saying, Spring cloud builds on Spring boot only.